# Eclipse Paho C Client SSL connection on iOS

Tags: ios, eclipse, xcode, ssl, mqtt

I've been trying for days to establish a secure (**SSL/TLS**) connection to an **IBM MessageSight Virtual Appliance** using the equivalent of the latest **Eclipse Paho C Client** library, which is **IBM WebSphere MQ Client Pack MA9B for Mobile V1.0.0.4**.

## Client Side:

### Objective-C Code:

```
...
client = [client initWithHosts:hosts ports:ports clientId:clientId];

ConnectOptions *opts = [[ConnectOptions alloc] init];
opts.timeout         = 3600;
/*
opts.userName        = @"******";
opts.password        = @"******";
 */
opts.cleanSession    = cleanSession;
opts.willMessage     = nil;

NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *ksFile     = [mainBundle pathForResource: @"ClientKeyStore" ofType: @"pem"];
NSString *pkFile     = [mainBundle pathForResource: @"ClientKey" ofType: @"pem"];
NSString *tsFile     = [mainBundle pathForResource: @"RootCAKey" ofType: @"pem"];

if (DEBUG) {
    NSLog(@"Bundle         ==> %@", mainBundle);
    NSLog(@"ClientKeyStore ==> %@", ksFile);
    NSLog(@"ClientKey      ==> %@", pkFile);
    NSLog(@"TrustStore     ==> %@", tsFile);
}

SSLOptions *ssl          = [[SSLOptions alloc] init];
ssl.enableServerCertAuth = NO;
// ssl.enabledCipherSuites  = @"SHA2";
ssl.keyStore             = ksFile;
ssl.privateKey           = pkFile;
ssl.privateKeyPassword   = @"******";
ssl.trustStore           = tsFile;

opts.sslProperties = ssl;

[client connectWithOptions:opts invocationContext:self onCompletion:callback];
```

This is the Objective-C code I've used to interact with the C library through it's wrapper (MqttOCClient.h/m).

### Now the specs:

- iOS 7.1 onwards, Xcode 6.3.1 (Simulator).
- iOS 8.3, Xcode 6.3.1 (iPhone 5S).
- MQTT iOS Client: IBM WebSphere MQ Client Pack MA9B for Mobile V1.0.0.4 (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mm.tc.doc/tc10120_.htm).

### Trace:

I've enabled trace mode on the library through the 2 Environment Variables:

```
MQTT_C_CLIENT_TRACE_LEVEL = MAXIMUM
MQTT_C_CLIENT_TRACE       = ON
```

and this is the output:

```
D] >>MessagingClient::connectWithOptions
I] first serverURI is ssl://example.com:1884
=========================================================
                   Trace Output
Product name: Paho Asynchronous MQTT C Client Library
Version: ##MQTTCLIENT_VERSION_TAG##
Build level: ##MQTTCLIENT_BUILD_TAG##
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1h 5 Jun 2014
OpenSSL flags: compiler: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -miphoneos-version-min=7.1  -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -O3 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-common
OpenSSL build timestamp: built on: Thu Jun  5 14:59:07 BST 2014
OpenSSL platform: platform: iphoneos-cross
OpenSSL directory: OPENSSLDIR: "/tmp/openssl-1.0.1h-iOS-i386"
=========================================================
19691231 200000.000 Allocating 32 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/LinkedList.c line 56 ptr 0x7a068df0
19691231 200000.000 (42856916)  (1)> Socket_outInitialize:124
19691231 200000.000 (42856916)   (2)> SocketBuffer_initialize:85
19691231 200000.000 Allocating 32 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/SocketBuffer.c line 73 ptr 0x79f75480
19691231 200000.000 Allocating 1008 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/SocketBuffer.c line 75 ptr 0x7a917000
19691231 200000.000 Allocating 32 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/LinkedList.c line 56 ptr 0x79f791c0
19691231 200000.000 (42856916)   (2)< SocketBuffer_initialize:89
19691231 200000.000 Allocating 32 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/LinkedList.c line 56 ptr 0x79f792a0
19691231 200000.000 Allocating 32 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/LinkedList.c line 56 ptr 0x79f786f0
19691231 200000.000 Allocating 32 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/LinkedList.c line 56 ptr 0x7a26ba90
19691231 200000.000 (42856916)  (1)< Socket_outInitialize:137
19691231 200000.000 Allocating 32 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/LinkedList.c line 56 ptr 0x7a26bcb0
19691231 200000.000 Allocating 32 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/LinkedList.c line 56 ptr 0x7a26ba20
19691231 200000.000 (42856916)  (1)> SSLSocket_initialize:398
19691231 200000.000 Allocating 1808 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/SSLSocket.c line 414 ptr 0x7b8fd600
...
20150514 130126.866 (42856916)   (2)< SSL_create_mutex:313 (0)
20150514 130126.866 (42856916)   (2)> SSL_create_mutex:307
...
20150514 130126.867 (42856916)  (1)< SSLSocket_initialize:438 (1)
20150514 130126.867 Allocating 144 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/MQTTAsync.c line 374 ptr 0x79f75f10
20150514 130126.867 Allocating 32 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/MQTTAsync.c line 386 ptr 0x79f75fb0
20150514 130126.867 Allocating 32 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/LinkedList.c line 56 ptr 0x79ec7160
20150514 130126.867 Allocating 16 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/LinkedList.c line 93 ptr 0x79e78970
20150514 130126.867 Allocating 96 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/MQTTAsync.c line 391 ptr 0x79ec1840
20150514 130126.867 Allocating 32 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/LinkedList.c line 56 ptr 0x79ec1780
20150514 130126.867 Allocating 32 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/LinkedList.c line 56 ptr 0x79ed00c0
20150514 130126.867 Allocating 32 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/LinkedList.c line 56 ptr 0x79ec9090
20150514 130126.867 Allocating 32 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/MQTTAsync.c line 397 ptr 0x79ec2110
20150514 130126.867 (42856916)  (1)> MQTTPersistence_create:47
20150514 130126.867 (42856916)  (1)< MQTTPersistence_create:93 (0)
20150514 130126.867 (42856916)  (1)> MQTTPersistence_initialize:108
20150514 130126.867 (42856916)  (1)< MQTTPersistence_initialize:116 (0)
20150514 130126.867 (42856916)  (1)> MQTTAsync_restoreCommands:666
20150514 130126.867 0 commands restored for client 32c94ab93d29fda895b02f6
20150514 130126.867 (42856916)  (1)< MQTTAsync_restoreCommands:698 (0)
20150514 130126.867 (42856916)  (1)> MQTTAsync_restoreMessageQueue:1872
20150514 130126.867 0 queued messages restored for client 32c94ab93d29fda895b02f6
20150514 130126.867 (42856916)  (1)< MQTTAsync_restoreMessageQueue:1903 (0)
20150514 130126.867 Allocating 16 bytes in heap at file /Users/asm/workspace/Client/client_ios/iosMQTT/iosMQTT/mqttCClient/LinkedList.c line 93 ptr 0x79e7cef0
20150514 130126.867 (42856916) (0)< MQTTAsync_create:416 (0)
2015-05-14 13:01:26.867 SmartBanking[2616:607] D] C Client created
20150514 130126.867 (42856916) (0)> MQTTAsync_setCallbacks:1658
20150514 130126.867 (42856916) (0)< MQTTAsync_setCallbacks:1672 (0)
2015-05-14 13:01:26.868 SmartBanking[2616:607] D] Calling C client to make connection
20150514 130126.867 (42856916) (0)> MQTTAsync_connect:1990
20150514 130126.867 (42856916) (0)< MQTTAsync_connect:2177 (-8)
E] C client connect failed
Connection Error: ErrorCode=8  ErrorMessage=Unable to connect
D] <<MessagingClient::connectWithOptions
```

## Server Side:

- IBM MessageSight v1.1.0
- Server Certificate: 2048bits Self-Signed.
- Security is enabled and the Endpoint is up.
- User and Pass enabled.

## Side Notes:

- If I use a browser I can view the certificate, which means it can connect to the server.
- Works if I use Eclipse Paho for Java, validating the Server Certificate with the same TrustStore (which contains the Self-Signed CA).

I will appreciate if somebody who has make an SSL connection to MQTT from iOS using this library can point me to the right direction.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is with the cipherspec/ssl version you are using.  The Java default cipherspec may be supported by MessageSight 1.1, but the default iOS cipherspec may not be.

You should try setting a specific cipherspec that is in the [supported list](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCGGQ_1.1.0/com.ibm.ism.doc/Reference/_Topics/re00002_.html).